# Swift Protocols and Protocols Extensions With CollectionType

Tags: swift, protocols

I don't understand the return type for an array.indexOf() in swift.
When I command click the function it takes me to a protocol extension:

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element : Equatable {

/// Returns the first index where `value` appears in `self` or `nil` if
/// `value` is not found.
///
/// - Complexity: O(`self.count`).
func indexOf(element: Self.Generator.Element) -> Self.Index?
}
```

The method indexOf returns Self.Index?,

how does it know that its an Int?

Comment: Array.startIndex returns Int. thus Self.Index will be inferred to int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into Swift header for _CollectionDefaultsType, you will see the protocol definition as follows,

```
protocol _CollectionDefaultsType : SequenceType {

    /// A type that represents a valid position in the collection.
    ///
    /// Valid indices consist of the position of every element and a
    /// "past the end" position that's not valid for use as a subscript.
    typealias Index : ForwardIndexType

    /// The position of the first element in a non-empty collection.
    ///
    /// In an empty collection, `startIndex == endIndex`.
    var startIndex: Self.Index { get }

    /// The collection's "past the end" position.
    ///
    /// `endIndex` is not a valid argument to `subscript`, and is always
    /// reachable from `startIndex` by zero or more applications of
    /// `successor()`.
    var endIndex: Self.Index { get }

    /// Returns the first element of `self`, or `nil` if `self` is empty.
    var first: Self.Generator.Element? { get }
}
```

If you go through the Swift header file, you can see the definition of Array as follows

```
struct Array<T> : CollectionType, SequenceType, _CollectionDefaultsType, _CollectionGeneratorDefaultsType, MutableCollectionType, Sliceable, _Sliceable, _DestructorSafeContainer {

    /// The type of element stored by this `Array`.
    typealias Element = T

    /// Always zero, which is the index of the first element when non-empty.
    var startIndex: Int { get }

    /// A "past-the-end" element index; the successor of the last valid
    /// subscript argument.
    var endIndex: Int { get }
    subscript (index: Int) -> T

    /// Return a *generator* over the elements.
    ///
    /// - Complexity: O(1).
    func generate() -> IndexingGenerator<[T]>

    /// A type that can represent a sub-range of an `Array`.
    typealias SubSlice = ArraySlice<T>
    subscript (subRange: Range<Int>) -> ArraySlice<T>
}
```

The getter startIndex, endIndex, first are the ones which are implemented from the protocol **_CollectionDefaultsType**, whose type is **Self.Index**.  Now, if you look at the definition of the **indexOf** method, it is implemented as a protocol extension with the type of **Self.Index**.

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element : Equatable {

    /// Returns the first index where `value` appears in `self` or `nil` if
    /// `value` is not found.
    ///
    /// - Complexity: O(`self.count`).
    func indexOf(element: Self.Generator.Element) -> Self.Index?
}
```

Thus, the type **Index** gets inferred to Int from above two implementation.

By the way, if you type into playground to see the type Index inside Array, typing Array.Index, the autocomplete shows the type as Int,

[image]

Comment: I'm getting lost how this line "var startIndex: Int { get }" turns this other line " typealias Index : ForwardIndexType" into Int

Comment: The "typealias Index:ForwardIndexType" simply says that the type Index is something which implement "ForwardIndexType". But the inference is done from "var startIndex: Int" inside Array implementation. So think of it like, a protocol or protocol implementation does not know  what "Index" is, it simply knows that there is some type of Index, but when one of the variable in implementation is given a type to "Int", all other usage of "Index" will be inferred to as "Int"

Comment: Thank you, Im beginning to understand. Are there docs you can point me to ? The Prerelease iBook Swift 2.0 Protocol chapter does not talk about this.